# Headless Chrome Node API and Puppeteer installation

Tags: puppeteer, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

Throughout the process of installation chrome headless on a clean ubuntu 18.04 i faced quite a few issues. The setup guide on github is not sufficient for a clean ubuntu 18.04

The following are some errors and answer / solutions to setting up headless chrome an alternative to phantomjs.

Error 1

```
(node:23835) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"
    at Launcher.launch owlcommand.com /puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:112:15)
    at <anonymous>
(node:23835) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23835) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Error 2

```
(node:25272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
owlcommand.com /puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-594312/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

You only have to run the following command in Ubuntu 18.04

```
npm i puppeteer
```

Unfortunately this is not enough.

You will require the following Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

After which if you run it as per their example , you will receive an error

```
    (node:28469) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[1025/150325.817887:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

The solution to this is

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
```

Adding --no-sandbox

It will work accordingly then. The full working source code is below

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://owlcommand.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Solution to puppeteer@1.9.0~install: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s)**

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```

**Screenshot Size**

The default is really small, if the page you are testing is responsive, you can test it with different viewport settings. You can change its dimensions via the setViewport method.

```
await page.setViewport({
  width: 1600, 
  height: 1000
});
```

**Update for Latest Puppeteer (Aug 2020)**

sudo apt-get install libgbm1 (Required)

Comment: This is the perfect reference for installing Puppeter on server

Comment: Great answer. July 2020, I also had to `sudo apt-get install libgbm1`

Answer (score 5):

Update Nov-18: You don't require the --no-sandbox flag any longer, you should use the headless:false property in the object you send to .launch()

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 80,
    args: ['--window-size=1920,1080']
    });
```

Also make sure you have all the required debian dependencies installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

Answer (score 3):

and also install libgbm1

"puppeteer": "^3.1.0"

full cmd is

apt-get update && apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 ***libgbm1*** libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

Answer (score 0):

I had that kind of problem only when I tried to run a node application on Docker, so based on the answers given, I finally got it working with that Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    gconf-service \ 
    libasound2 \ 
    libatk1.0-0 \ 
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \ 
    libc6 \ 
    libcairo2 \ 
    libcups2 \ 
    libdbus-1-3 \ 
    libexpat1 \ 
    libfontconfig1 \ 
    libgcc1 \ 
    libgconf-2-4 \ 
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \ 
    libglib2.0-0 \ 
    libgtk-3-0 \ 
    libnspr4 \ 
    libpango-1.0-0 \ 
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \ 
    libstdc++6 \ 
    libx11-6 \ 
    libx11-xcb1 \ 
    libxcb1 \ 
    libxcomposite1 \ 
    libxcursor1 \ 
    libxdamage1 \ 
    libxext6 \ 
    libxfixes3 \ 
    libxi6 \ 
    libxrandr2 \ 
    libxrender1 \ 
    libxss1 \ 
    libxtst6 \ 
    ca-certificates \ 
    fonts-liberation \ 
    libappindicator1 \ 
    libnss3 \ 
    lsb-release \ 
    xdg-utils \ 
    wget \ 
    && npm i puppeteer
COPY . /app
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I changed the launch code as mentioned as well, it worked just fine that way:
`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem on Windows. I made asar as false and it got successful.

```
"build": { "asar":false, }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with fork of `buildkite/puppeteer` and found that with new Chrome (85) I had to install `libxss1` instead of `libgbm1` (as suggested in other comments)

So it looks like this at the moment ([link](https://github.com/dmk1111/docker-puppeteer/blob/495a5b52da2bc0458e7e53eba5e0efcb6f9dd386/Dockerfile)):

```
FROM node:12.18.3-buster-slim@sha256:dd6aa3ed10af4374b88f8a6624aeee7522772bb08e8dd5e917ff729d1d3c3a4f

RUN  apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y git \
     && apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y libxss1 wget gnupg ca-certificates \
     && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
     && apt-get update \
     # We install Chrome to get all the OS level dependencies, but Chrome itself
     # is not actually used as it's packaged in the node puppeteer library.
     # Alternatively, we could could include the entire dep list ourselves
     # (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)
     # but that seems too easy to get out of date.
     && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
     && wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh \
     && chmod +x /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: So much breaking changes over the years >.<